# Java-like null for string and ofstream arguments in c++

Tags: c++, null, arguments

I have some Java code (constructor)

```
RecursiveDescentParser
(
  std::string inputStream, 
  bool fileService, 
  std::string filePathName, 
  std::ofstream writer
)
{
  input_ = inputStream;
  tokenizer_ = new Tokenizer(inputStream);
  if (fileService == true){
      error = new ErrorHandling(fileService, std::move(writer));
  }
  else{
      error = new ErrorHandling(fileService, std::ofstream());
  }     
  compiled_ = "";
}

Tokenizer *tokenizer_;

std::string input_, compiled_;
```

I would like to emulate a call within c++

```
RecursiveDescentParser *parser = new RecursiveDescentParser
(
  stream, 
  false, 
  null, 
  null
);
```

If I use pointer arguments

```
std::string *str; std::ofstream *out
```

I can pass in nullptr but if I choose not to use pointer arguments, I can't pass null.
What can I do to simulate passing null to a std::string and std::ofstream?

Comment: Why not use default arguments and default initialize them?

Comment: you can use `boost::optional` or make another mechanism to tell your function that the parameter is not passed.

Comment: @jotep Default initialize them to what?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Empty string and stdout

Comment: @andre please read the question more carefully. OP says if I use pointers I can pass NULL but if I don't what can I do?

Comment: @jotep Except `std::cout` (which I assume you meant) isn't an `ofstream`, and an empty string might be a valid (non-null) input. In general, types don't have defined "null" values.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Why null them in the first place?

Comment: @MikeSeymour jotep may have a point to make.  If I choose default arguments, then I wouldn't have to pass anything and it would symbolically represent passing NULL.

Comment: @jotep: Because the question asks "how can I null them"?

Comment: Just a small side note: `std::ofstream writer` should be `std::ofstream& writer` - a stream can not be copied.

Comment: @andre Thank you. No wonder why I was mashing keys and randomly typing std::move(std::ofstream)

Comment: This looks like an XY problem.  In Java, all non-trivial objects' variables are roughly the equivalent of C++ pointers, with the actual data stored in the object located on a reference counted free store.  In C++, actual objects can be passed around directly in automatic storage. The first C++ solution you should reach for is to either have multiple overrides, or if appropriate default arguments. Something like `boost::optional` or taking pointer arguments also works. A lot of what the right answer is depends on what the body of `RecursiveDescentParser` does with "no argument here" parameters.

Comment: @Yakk Body added to RecursiveDescentParser

Comment: `filePathName` is not used in the body, eliminate it from the interface.  `writer`'s use is conditional on the `bool fileService` state -- having both that `bool` and an optional `writer` seems questionable.

Comment: Is `RecursiveDescentParser` a method?  Is it `virtual`?  Where does `error` come from? The other two variables used in the function without being declared with a trailing `_`?

Comment: @Yakk `I have some Java code (constructor)` is in the question at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers are one option as you say; but create complications as you need to either manage the objects separately, or use smart pointers. Shared pointers are a possibility, and give semantics quite similar to Java's object references (only with reference counting rather than garbage collection).

For a nullable object type, you could use [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html), or implement your own nullable wrapper class. There is talk of `optional` being included in a future standard library; but for now, you need Boost for that.

Alternatively, it might make more sense to provide a second constructor which does not take those arguments at all.

Comment: I read [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) and would like a clear concrete example of how it would be implemented for parameters.

Comment: @Mushy: The parameter would be `boost::optional<std::string>`, and you could pass either a string or `boost::none`.

Comment: What is the #include<> path for [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)?

Comment: @Mushy: `boost/optional.hpp`

Comment: I having a problem with boost::optional<std::ofstream> related to no copy/no assign. If I specify, for example, const boost::optional<std::ofstream> &writer as an argument, how am I to do this?

Comment: @Mushy: As someone noted in the comments, that will have to be a pointer or reference anyway - `ofstream` objects aren't copyable, so you can't pass them by value.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would change your usage:

```
RecursiveDescentParser
(
  std::string inputStream, 
  bool fileService = false, 
  std::string filePathName = "", 
  std::ofstream* writer = NULL
)

RecursiveDescentParser *parser = new RecursiveDescentParser(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options - either create a wrapper class that represents an optional value or use pointers. I strongly recommend the first option.

Also in some cases you may considered an empty string to be equivalent to not set value.

Answer (score 0):

sadly, strings in C++ are objects, and unlike java, C++ objects cannot be null.

From what I understand, you are creating a constructor to a RecursiveDescentParser.
The constructor's job is to initialize the object.

If the constructor was allowed to accept a pointer, it could accept a null path string, then it will have been created with a null path string, because it is constructor's job is  to initialize all fields, and null fields are not initialized, this would not be a good solution.

My suggestion is to make the constructor private, but create a public method that can accept the parameters the constructor would, but also a pointer to the string rather than the object. If the path string pointer is null, throw an exception, or return an error object. If the path string is valid, create a new parser from reference to the string pointed to by path string pointer, and return this reference.

Although, I could be totally off, but this is just a suggestion, and I welcome all constructive criticisms on why this would not work.

Comment: C++ `string`s are no more references than `int`s are references.  C++ `std::string` are full on value types.

Comment: Strings are not references, they're objects. But you're correct that objects can't be null.

Comment: Modified it. No need to downvote, I am willing to correct all inaccuracies, I am merely suggesting a solution.

Comment: You might want to change or remove the paragraph about "null fields" too, since that makes no sense at all.

Comment: I modified it to make more sense.